# Find and classify the singularities of $f(z)=\left(2z\cosh\left(\frac{1}{z+1}\right)\right)^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a problem in my introductory course in complex analysis. I think there's one singularity at $z=-1$, but don't know how to prove it. I think (prompted by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616058/taylor-expansion-of-cosh2x) question) that
\begin{align}
f(z) 
& = \left(2z\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z+1}}+e^{-\frac{1}{z+1}}}{2}\right)^2 \\
& =z^2\left(e^{\frac{2}{z+1}}+2+e^{-\frac{2}{z+1}}\right) \\
& = z^2\left(2+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n}{(z+1)^nn!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-2)^n}{(z+1)^nn!}\right) \\
& = 2z^2\left(1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^{2n}}{(z+1)^{2n}(2n)!}\right)
\end{align}
but I don't know how to get this into a Laurent series in $z-1$ to show whether the singularity is essential or removable.

Comment: It is already in a Laurent series form (just because you don't see any $z,z^2,...$ etc. terms doesn't mean it's not a Laurent series! All terms are multiples of $(z-(-1))^n$). The singularities of $e^{1/z}$ or similar are essential, since the Laurent series has infinitely terms of negative power

Comment: @FShrike Doesn't the $2z^2(1+$ stop the whole expression from being a Laurent series? In particular, for the purpose of finding the residue can that part just be ignored?

Comment: It really doesn’t matter. But, $2z^2=2(z+1)^2-4(z+1)+2$ which will fit into the standard Laurent form.

Comment: @FShrike Do you mean it really doesn't matter as long as it can be made to fit into the standard Laurent form? I'll be surprised if any expression at all can be added to a Laurent series and the resulting sum can still be called a Laurent series.

Comment: The sum of two Laurent series about the same base point is again a Laurent series. Since $z\mapsto z^2$ is an entire function, its Laurent expansion at $z=-1$ will not contribute to the negative powers, and thus will not affect the classification of the singularity (if there is even a singularity at all)

Comment: @FShrike OK, I think I get that. Finally (I hope), can you tell me how to interpret the $(-2)!$ that seems to appear in the $n=-1$ residue term?

Comment: There are no negative factorial terms in the Laurent series. If you use the series in the form currently presented in your post, all $n$ are nonnegative and you are seeing $(2n)!$, the normal factorial. If you switch to a series of the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n(z+1)^n$ then all terms with a factorial will be terms $(-2n)!$ with $n\le0$, so there are no problems

Comment: @FShrike Thanks for your help. If you care to write up your comments as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. Otherwise I'll accept Meowdog's answer in order to close the question. It's less relevant for me than our exchange, but I imagine there will be people who find it useful.

Comment: Thanks, but no worries, I’ll leave them here since they’re quite specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only singularity has been correctly identified as $-1$. It is also true that
$$
f(z) = \left(2z\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z+1}}+e^{-\frac{1}{z+1}}}{2}\right)^2.
$$
Also note that for $z_n := \frac{1}{n}-1$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (which converges to the singularity), we have:
$$
\lvert f(z_n) \rvert = \left( 2\left( \tfrac{1}{n}-1\right) \frac{e^{n}+ e^{-n}}{2}\right)^2 \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \infty
$$
Conversely, for $w_n := \frac{i}{n} - 1$, it holds that
$$
\lvert f(w_n) \rvert = \left \lvert 2\left( \tfrac{i}{n}-1\right) \frac{e^{-in}+e^{in}}{2}  \right \rvert^2 \leq 2\left \lvert \tfrac{i}{n}-1 \right \rvert^2 \left(\lvert e^{in} \rvert^2 + \lvert e^{-in} \rvert^2 \right) = 4 \left \lvert \tfrac{i}{n}-1 \right \rvert^2 \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0.
$$

This means that the singularity can't be a pole: If it were a pole (and it can't be removable because of the sequence $z_n$) then the Laurent series would look like this $(\ell \geq 1)$:
$$
f(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^\ell a_k (z+1)^{-k} + \underbrace{\sum_{k = 0}^\infty b_k(z+1)^k}_{:=T(z)}
$$
Since $f$ is holomorphic, $T$ converges locally around -1 and is hence a continuous power series. This would mean that
$$
\lim_{z \rightarrow -1} \lvert f(z) \rvert  = \infty,
$$
since $T$ stays bounded.
So because of the sequence $w_n$, $-1$ can only be an essential singularity.

**This holds in general:** If $p \in \mathbb{C}$ is a singularity of holomorphic $f: \mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace p \rbrace \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ it is an essential singularity iff there exist sequences $w_n, z_n \rightarrow p$ such that $f(w_n) \rightarrow 0$ and $\lvert f(z_n) \rvert \rightarrow \infty$.